Not able load to asset images/fonts avaible using vite config
I have project structure as shown below.
This project am using as bundle.js in other application.
So, the assets folder images, font file like .ttf, woff are not been loaded and showing 404 error.
The other application does not have asset folder, but bundle.js does have, is it relative path issue.
I am using vite.config and lit element. can help please
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ dist/
│  ├─ assets/
|  |    | index.js
|  |    | index.css        
│  ├─ index.html
├─ index.html
├─ main.js
├─ style.scss
├─ package.json
   vite.config.js



You need to move them to the /public folder. See Static Asset Handling in the docs.
